# SQL:- split sql row's into multiple rows by dividing to it

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to split sql row's into multiple rows by dividing to it.
Just assume i have below records,

```
No  name  date        sub-total  tax    total
1  Test   02-11-2017    5000     750    5750
```

Now I want records like below by dividing 3 to the above sub total, tax and total amount.

```
No  name  date        sub-total  tax    total
1  Test   02-11-2017    1666.66   250    1916.66
1  Test   02-11-2017    1666.66   250    1916.66
1  Test   02-11-2017    1666.66   250    1916.66
```

Please suggest..
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a cross join:

```
select No,
    name,
    date,
    subtotal / 3.0 subtotal,
    tax / 3.0 tax,
    total / 3.0 total
from your_table t
cross join (
    select 1 i union all select 2 union all select 3
    ) x
```